# Not sure how to repeat options after invalid string input

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgY71.png)
This is a screenshot of my code. At current, if the user inputs and invalid command, it automatically closes the program. What I would like it to do instead of closing the porgram, is give the user another chance to input a correct command.

While I have found ways to try and do this online, none have really worked correctly, usually because they were made with a single correct option in mind, as opposed to two. The most recent solution I tried simply printed "Invalid Input" over and over again without giving the user the option to enter a valid input.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code, post the code itself and moreover - a reproducible piece of code, which we can run and see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

put it in a while loop

```py
while True:
    choice1 = input("")
    if choice1 == "yes":
        break
    elif choice1 == "no":
        clear()
        print("You decicde not to seek shelter at the house.")
        print("Night falls, and you are ambushed and killed by mutant hounds. Ending 1/?")
        break
    else:
        print("invalid command")
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I possibly should chide you for not posting your code example as text along with a minimal executable example, it appears that you might be new to Python so I'll give you some leeway.

Following is one of many possible solutions to your issue, and I am sure if you scoured the internet, you could find even more elegant methods for the prompting and testing that you want to do (e.g., the possible valid values might be passed in as well to make the prompting more flexible).  With that, here is one way to go that encapsulates the user prompting as a function and then returns an answer to the calling part of the program once the user has entered in a proper value.

```
def prompt(question, options):       # An example of prompting for user entry as a function
    while True:
        entry = input(question)

        if entry.lower() not in options:
            print("An invalid entry was made - please try again")
            continue

        else:
            break

    return entry.lower()

def main():

    choice1 = prompt("Do you want to seek shelter at the house? ", ['yes', 'no'])

    if choice1 == "yes":
        print("Good choice")
    else:
        print("You decide not to seek shelter at the house")
        print("Night falls, and you are ambushed and killed by mutant hounds")

main()
```

Testing this method out results in the following terminal output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Choice$ python3 YesNo.py 
Do you want to seek shelter at the house? yes
Good choice
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Choice$ python3 YesNo.py 
Do you want to seek shelter at the house? nope
An invalid entry was made - please try again
Do you want to seek shelter at the house? no
You decide not to seek shelter at the house
Night falls, and you are ambushed and killed by mutant hounds
```

I took a bit of artistic license with your choice and results, but this should provide some food for thought.  The main takeaway from this is probably to delve into some Python tutorial literature, especially as it pertains to functions and loops using "continue" and "break" statements.